# What does it mean for the $|x - y_n|$ be convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $A$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence on $A$

Then claim: $|y_n - x|$ is convergent.

I know what it means for a sequence to be a convergent. A sequence $(y_n)$ is convergent if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall n \geq N, d(y_n,x) < \epsilon$

But clearly, in the above question $x$ could lie well off of $A$. So that $d(y_n,x) < \epsilon$ bit is never true. But if $d(x,y) = |x-y|$, then doesn't convergent $|y_n - x|$ mean exactly $d(y_n, x) < \epsilon$?

What is the proper definition that $|y_n - x|$ is convergent?

Comment: Clearly you have missed some hypothesis. Most likely that $(y_n)$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(y_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence in $A \subseteq \Bbb R^n$, and $x \in \Bbb R^n$, then $(\|y_n-x\|)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of real numbers, so it makes sense to wonder if this sequence converges or not. Since the norm is continuous, you can guess that it will converge to $\|y-x\|$, if $y_n \to y$. Meaning that given $\epsilon > 0$, you can find $N > 0$ such that $n > N$ implies $|\|y_n-x\|-\|y-x\||<\epsilon$. Can you go on?